# Running Classic ASP.NET on a different IDE

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to run classic ASP.NET on a different IDE? I am having trouble with Visual Studio because it runs very slow on my PC. If there are any other options?

Comment: By `classic asp.net` do you mean web forms? Because ASP.NET can also run MVC and Web API

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're right sorry I was referring to web forms. Thank you for clearing that out

Answer (score 0):

*Visual Studio Code* is a lightweight IDE you could use and has good integration with .Net

https://code.visualstudio.com

It has the added advantage that it runs on Linux and Mac as well.
I haven't used it much myself, but it's highly extensible and very easy to use. It features intellisense, good integration with nuget package management, git, etc..

Comment: Yeah VS Code is great but how do I run the whole process with just VS Code? Can you give me some references? Thank you

Comment: @SamuelMarvinAguilos there are a *lot* of articles, blog posts and tutorialson how to use VS Code. In fact, newer doc articles contain instructions for both Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code and the command line. That includes articles about MVC and Web API

Comment: @SamuelMarvinAguilos Here are but a few sites of the many which can guide you:
https://daveabrock.com/2018/03/05/full-stack-development-in-vs-code-with-asp-net-core/
https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/visual-studio-code-aspdotnet-projects
https://www.telerik.com/blogs/developing-asp-net-5-web-apps-with-visual-studio-code